# react-native white screen after splash until I make a change in code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm getting a white screen in my react-native app after the splash screen. If however, I then hit command+s from any file in the project, to save it (regardless of changes or not), the app refreshes and then loads fine, no issue. Then if I am to reload (command+r) from the metro console, I just get a white screen again, until I save something else.

I can't work out what or why I might have changed to trigger this, revering all recent changes still makes no difference. Has anyone experienced this before?

My only console output is :

```
 WARN  Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/components/MapView.js -> node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/components/Geojson.js -> node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/components/MapView.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle. 
    at App (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=uk.co.dropless&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:166115:78)
    at HeadlessCheck (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=uk.co.dropless&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:1368:26)
    at RCTView
    at View
    at RCTView
    at View
    at AppContainer (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=uk.co.dropless&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:76239:36)
```

Comment: do you have any video/recording that show the problem?

Answer (score 0):

some where in your application you did cyclic imports

lets say you have "File1.js" and "File2.js"

in File1.js

```
import File2 from "./File2"
```

and in File2.js

```
import File1 from "./File1"
```

Comment: Ah I see is that what the warning is saying, looks like the one it warns about is in node_modules though, not sure if thats out of my control